# Entering data in an input field with ng-options in angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I have the following array in my angular js controller -

```
    $scope.Data = [

    {Day: 'Monday', Start: '10.00', Finish: '15.30'},
    {Day: 'Tuesday', Start: '10.00', Finish: '16.30'},
    {Day: 'Tuesday', Start: '10.00', Finish: '12.30'},

    ]
$scope.overTime = 0;
```

In my view i'm looping through this array like this:

```
  <div ng-repeat="a in Data track by $index">
   <strong> {{a.Day}}
   <input ng-model="a.Start"/>
   <input ng-model="a.Finish/>
   <span> Add over Time </span>
   <input type=""text" placeholder="Add overtime" ng-model="addovertime"\>

  </div>
```

Everything is working fine as expected but the only issue im having is adding the overtime input fields. As you can see in my code ,a user can add some overtime on either days  the issue is that for example if i needed to add overtime for Monday, anything i enter in the Monday overtime input filed also appears  in the overtime for Tuesday and Wednesday an   vice versa. This is because i'm binding the data on overtime? maybe i'm not really sure  but how would i go about to achieve thus ? 
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you store the overtime in a scope variable, and not per data item. To store overtime individually for each item, do:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Add overtime" ng-model="a.overtime">
```

Answer (score 1):

Go through this,create separate scope each overtime

```js
var jimApp = angular.module("mainApp",  []);

jimApp.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){
      $scope.Data = [

    {Day: 'Monday', Start: '10.00', Finish: '15.30'},
    {Day: 'Tuesday', Start: '10.00', Finish: '16.30'},
    {Day: 'Tuesday', Start: '10.00', Finish: '12.30'},

    ];
    $scope.overTime = 0;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="a in Data track by $index">
   <strong> {{a.Day}}</strong>
   <input ng-model="a.Start"/>
   <input ng-model="a.Finish"/>
   <span> Add over Time </span>
   <input type="text" placeholder="Add overtime" ng-model="a.addovertime" >

  </div>
</div>
```